# Restricting fields in XML schema

Tags: xml

I have a schema which is pretty complex. Here is an example of how one of my XML tag looks like

```
<STEP STEPTYPE="something" ACTOR="someAgent" TRACKNUM="0" VIDEO_ID="2" ... and so on>
```

Actually for each STEPTYPE (audio, video, display, speech etc) I have some related attributes (like for example, I need VIDEO_ID only for STEPTYPE="VIDEO", similarly, I need TRACKNUM to appear only when I use STEPTYPE="AUDIO")

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is XML Schema documentation on Complex Type Step.  Please Try to create your code, and if you have problems, then post your code, so we can help you with your errors.

http://www.fpml.org/spec/fpml-4-5-5-tr-1/html/schemaRef/fpml-shared-4-5.xsd.html_type_Step.html